# how to specify local source path for example like angular in node_modules in total.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

So, I would like to have a simple chart in web page (with websockets), but it must be available offline.
First thing I did, I've downloaded **empty project**, then `npm install total.js`, then `npm install n3-charts`. Now I need to specify path to local file and here I bumped into two questions:

1) Can I have "index.html" with headers of its own, or all must be put inside "layout.html" (will they combine)? How would index.htm then look like?

2) Wherever I put, path seems to not to work because (I guess) path is wrong. I've tried `<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js">` and to place that to layout.htm, but no success.

UPDATE: there is a folder "public/js" where you can put js files, but that would imply that node_modules folder is just not to be used and that all of the files you need are to be copied to "public/js". Is this the way it was intended?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for delay.

1. you can use `section`, [documentation](https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#pages~View%20engine)
2. of course, you have to create another `node_modules` directory in `public` folder: `/app/public/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js` and then it will work.

**YOUR UPDATE:** you can rename it as you wish